# How to generate a sitemap for Doxygen documentation?

Tags: doxygen, sitemap

I would like to generate a sitemap for my project documentation generated by Doxygen, how can I make it?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What do you mean by a "a sitemap for my project documentation generated by Doxygen"

Comment: 1.9.4. I would like to put the docs generated by Doxygen on my website, and submit a sitemap.xml to Google.

Comment: I don't know how a sitemap for google looks like but maybe you can get  some inspiration from the doxygen treeview (starting wit navtreedata.js and working from there.

Comment: @albert Sitemaps are XML files. Here's [a sitemap](https://kitswas.github.io/git-for-all/sitemap.xml) for example.

Comment: @Kitswas In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map I read: "The basic premise is that some sites have a large number of dynamic pages that are only available through the use of forms and user entries. ", the documentation generated by doxygen is more of a static nature. Best might be to create an enhancement request in the doxygen github bug tracker  and also mention a reference to the "statndard" https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Comment: @albert HTML pages generated via Doxygen have a **lot** of dynamic content. _[I have no idea why]_ e.g., See https://kitswas.github.io/CPU-scheduling-simulator/ with JS enabled and disabled to feel the difference. Without JS, only the primary content area of the index.html page is shown. Web crawlers do not execute JS scripts. So, the only way to inform them is to use a sitemap or submit the links manually to each search engine. _(Ouch)_

Comment: @Kitswas There is indeed quite a bit of "dynamic" content in the js files, though this is static as well (in my opinion) as it is generated at the moment the documentation is generated and not generated based on an underlying database. So a bit of a semantic discussion. I think the problem is more a problem of the webcrawlers. I faced a similar problem so I just wrote a small (*nix) script that looks for all files and places the result in a (dedicated) file like: `find . -name \*html | sed -e 's%.*%<a href="&">&</a>%'`

Comment: "is generated at the moment the documentation is generated and not generated based on an underlying database" - That's why I wonder _why_ they do it. It just slows down everything.

Comment: @albert I wonder if the content added using JS could be directly generated. Here are the benefits: (1) the js would not have to be fetched and executed, resulting in faster page load times and lower resource usage on the users' end; (2) the links would be present in the HTML - this provides a major boost to search rankings and is a primary reason(the other being speed) why people use static sites and SSR.

Comment: @Kitswas With "the content added using JS could be directly generated" you mean the content that is accessible through the treeview? This would mean that you would lose the possibility of collapsing tree and a very unclear table of contents

Comment: @albert We could have something like the contents section or the hamburger menu button on [any Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button). The menu button can show a dropdown even with JS disabled. The contents, without JS, are shown as a nested list instead. The point is, there should be minimal loss of textual info when scripts are not executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253427/discussion-between-kitswas-and-albert).